# Call a method in a class many times and the variable stays consistent

Tags: python, python-3.x

Writing a hangman program for Python and want a variable (self.masked_word) to stay consistent as I call the method many times...

For instance if the secret word is 'hello' and I play:

game.guess('h'), then game.guess('l'), game.get_masked_word() should return:'h_ll_'...

Currently, playing both only returns the last letter guessed... '__ll_'.

Have tried moving self.masked_word around from **init** to guess(), I just think I am misunderstanding how to create non-static variables that persist within classes. Thanks

```
STATUS_WIN = "win"
STATUS_LOSE = "lose"
STATUS_ONGOING = "ongoing"

class Hangman(object):
    def __init__(self, secret_word):
        self.secret_word = secret_word
        self.status = STATUS_ONGOING
        self.remaining_guesses = 9
        self.masked_word = ''

    def guess(self, guess):
        if self.secret_word.find(guess) >= 0:
            self.masked_word = list(map(lambda n: '_' if n != guess else n, self.secret_word))
        else:
            self.remaining_guesses -= 1

        if self.remaining_guesses < 0:
            self.status = STATUS_LOSE
            raise Exception("Vous avez déjà perdu!")
            return ("You lose! :(")
        elif guess is '' or guess is None:
            return (f"You have {self.remaining_guesses} guesses left. Répondez cette fois avec un lettre.")
        else:
            return (f"You have {self.remaining_guesses} guesses left.")

    def remaining_guesses(self):
        return self.remaining_guesses

    def get_masked_word(self):
        return ''.join(self.masked_word)

    def get_status(self):
        return self.status

game = Hangman('hello')
print(game.guess('h'))
print(game.guess('l'))
print(game.get_masked_word())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with the scope of the variable `masked_word` but that you destroy and recreate it on every guess. A possible solution could be:

Prefill the variable with `_`s on init:

```
def __init__(self, secret_word):
    ...
    self.masked_word = ['_' for _ in secret_word]
```

then only reveal the letters guessed in this turn:

```
def guess(self, guess):
    if self.secret_word.find(guess) >= 0:
        for i, letter in enumerate(self.secret_word):
            if letter == guess:
                self.masked_word[i] = letter
    else:
        self.remaining_guesses -= 1
```

This will result in:

```
You have 9 guesses left.
h_ll_
```